# How to connect to SAP from Salesforce with the SAP wsdl

Tags: integration, webservices

Having SAP WSDL file how can I connect to SAP from Salesforce ?

After connecting with salesforce, I only want to view the data.

kindly anyone tell how to resolve this.
Thanks,
Regards,
Udaya

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, Udaya. Please read our FAQ. As it stands, this question is likely to be closed because it is overly broad and you have not shown any research. Can you update your question to something more specific then asking how to use a WSDL file? There are many generic tutorials available for that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want to import the wsdl into salesforce and then use it to make an apex callout from salesforce to retrieve data.

To import the wsdl, go to Setup>Develop>Apex Classes 
Click the Generate from WSDL button and it will let you import your wsdl and generate apex classes for you. (The xsd cannot be a separate file)

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm

Comment: Thanks for reply,i am getting this error  when generate apex classes                                                      Apex Generation Failed
Unsupported schema type: {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType

Comment: is the xsd separate to the wsdl? if it is it needs to be flattened and embedded into the wsdl

Comment: THanks for the response Techtrekker. As I am new to salesforce i am not aware of xsd! can you please elaborate it and tell the procedure.i used Enterprise WSDL but it generated an error..Should i use Enterprise or partner Wsdl or any if i am integrating with sap??

Comment: The Salesforce Enterprise or Partner WSDL is for importing in an external system to communicate with Salesforce. To make a call to SAP, you need to import the SAP WSDL into Salesforce.

Comment: Agree, please try importing the SAP WSDL, if you have any errors with that we can try to help.

Comment: Now am getting this error:Apex Generation Failed
Unable to find soap 1.1 address when generate apex code

Comment: Now i convert this WSDL file into apex classes next step what can i do for that.

Comment: You need to use the generated classes to make a callout to the webservice to retrieve the data you want to display. http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts

Comment: change anyType to String or number.